# Formatting a Facebook Feed in a Twitter Bootstrap site

Tags: css, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, layout, feed

Has anyone been able to format a Facebook feed in a Twitter Bootstrap site? I have a site that uses the Facebook feed that currently does not use Bootstrap. Curious to know what issues and advice anyone has about it. The feed is but so flexible; I've had issues with fitting it in the current site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to the [activity feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity/)?

Comment: @StevenV yes the activity feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got some bad news for you. Most Facebook embeddable items are `<iframe>`'s. That means Facebook is in complete control of the look, feel and behavior of the content. Because of the same origin policy you can't even use Javascript to attempt to force styles upon the `<iframe>`.

Facebook does give you some basic options like width, height and color scheme when you embed it. If you're looking for 100% control and customization you probably want to look into the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/) instead.

Comment: I figured this would be the answer! I knew it was iframed in, I thought maybe someone had some workaround to it. Thank you for the answer!